# I want to get a metrics from host and jmx port through java

Tags: java, curl, jmx, nagios, metric

I got the metrics from JMX port by using the Nagios agent through curl command here is the syntax.

```
curl -s -X POST http://${hostname}:${agentport}/p1/kdc/monitor -d " {\"hostname\": \"${hostname}\", \"port\": \"${jmxport}\", \"metric\": \"${metric}\"}"'

curl -s -X POST http://manikya.devops.com/p1/kdc/monitor -d '{"hostname":"manikya.devops.com", "port":"9999", "metric": "bytes_in_per_second"}'
```

I want the same thing by Java.

Answer (score 0):

There are a large number of JMX plug-ins available on the Nagios Exchange that give you what you want, you can find them here: [Nagios/JMX plug-ins](https://exchange.nagios.org/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=search&Itemid=74&searchword=JMX)

Comment: Converting CURL request to HTTP Request Java